# How to distinguish the different probabilities ?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In Probability.  How we can identify from the Question that the Question will solved with what type of probability? 
How to distinguish the different probabilities branches or types  ?

Comment: The easy answer is with lots of practice. There is no "one simple trick". That being said, there are a few key properties that are good to look for: is it several independent trials? Are the trials dependant upon one another? Does order matter?

Comment: Actually i am having problem in understanding the Question. I did not even get, that what technique should be used to solve the question.

Comment: If you post the specific question here, it will be easier for us to help you analyze it and tell you how to think about it.

Comment: A Lego Robotics Workshop is being conducted at University. Robots are constructed with NXT 2.0. A team constructs a sumo robot with the LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 witch wins 7 out of 10 competitions. Determine the probability that the sumo robot would have done at least this well without the latest EV3?